# Why do my horizontal toolstrips keep stacking verticaly?

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstrip, toolstripcontainer

I'm using a ToolStripContainer that contains three ToolStrips. At design time I move the ToolStrips to the positions I want them in, which is in a horizontal row across the top of the form like this:

[image]

I then close and save the Form. However, if I open the form up again the ToolStrips end up stacked up on the left side of the ToolStripContainer like this:

[image]

How can I keep the ToolStrips in the positions that I specify?

Comment: Can you post the code you have that defines the ToolStripContainer and adds the ToolStrips.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug with Visual Studio.
I've had the same issues for years.
The only way I've found is to programmatically set all the ToolStrips' **Dock** property to **Right**.
Do this in the Form's constructor, just after the call to **InitializeComponent**.

Comment: What a weird bug. This works, they still screw up in the designer but they stack correctly at runtime. Very weird. Thanks :)